# Mysql date select from string

Tags: mysql

i've issue I try this query, do not return any rows. just 0 rows. Even tho there is data matching the request..

```
select * from repairshop_reservations where date = DATE_FORMAT("11/06/2017 20:00:00", '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s"');
```

Currently my content of the selected table look like this
[image: Content of table]

The data value of column Date is datetime

Comment: Try:

`SELECT * FROM repairshop_reservations WHERE date = "11/06/2017 20:00:00";`

Comment: Default date format is as in your screenshot: `where date = '2017-06-11 20:00:00'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use str_to_date  in this way you can control the proper formatting of the date when you don't use the standard  mysql format

```
select * from repairshop_reservations 
where date = str_to_date('11/06/2017 20:00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: you have an extra "

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich   correct answer .. updated ..thanks

Comment: I think what the OP wants is to have the entire row returned, but it's good to have an example of the str_to_date function in the question page for others to see. You should include in your answer when it's best to use str_to_date and when not.

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich   .thanks for suggestion answer updated  with a brief explanation

Answer (score 1):

You are not inserting a column in your table, so you won't have to define a data type for it. That means that, you are not making changes to the *conceptual scheme* of your database.

Considering that your table is implemented correctly, the SQL query you would need to give you the desirable result would be:

```
SELECT * FROM repairshop_reservations
WHERE date = "11/06/2017 20:00:00";
```

You use the WHERE clause, to filter your record and get an output with a 
specified condition. In plain English, what you want to do is:
*Select and print for me, **every column** from the **repairshop_reservations** table, that has listed **date** as "11/06/2017 20:00:00"*